# Test void with karma jasmine angular2

Tags: angular, jasmine, void, karma-mocha

I'm trying to test my code with jasmine and karma.

When I test a method that returns a value  it's ok. But my problem is how can I test a void method (that return nothing) for example this one:

```
public aj(a: Array<x>, p: x) {
 if (a.indexOf(p) < 0) {
   a.push(p);
  }
 }
```

With this function I check if an array of object `x contains an object  or no.

If it is not the case I add it to the array. That's all.

I test it this way

```
  it('', () => {
  let component= new synthese(consoService);
   let x = [pHC,pHP]
   spyOn(component,'aj');
   expect(component.aj(x,pI)).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });
```

I got this error

```
Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.
Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Can anyone help me, please? I tried but I always get errors.

Comment: That function still has side-effects, it still *does* something. So *test the thing it does* - call it with an array and make sure the item gets added to it under the appropriate circumstances (and doesn't in the others). To put it another way: you must have had a reason to write that function, something you needed it to do: does it do that? Beyond that, please give a [mcve] of what you tried, what errors you get.

Comment: And without a [mcve], at least post the code you already tried, so that we have an idea of what is your issue.

Comment: jonrsharpe , trichetriche i updated it. Could you please take a look. Thanks

Comment: You are simply spying on the method and expecting it to be called, But there is no code in between that will actually invoke the method.

Comment: if i try to invoke this method by calling it  like that :                                                                                              
         it('', () => {
         let component= new synthese(consoService);
         let x = [pHC,pHP];                                                                                               
         let xx = [posteHC,posteHP];
         component.concatenerSansDoublons(x,xx);
        spyOn(component,'aj');
        expect(component.aj(x,pI)).toHaveBeenCalled();

       });      that change nothing  @AmitChigadani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```js
it('', () => {
  const component = new synthese(consoService);
  const x = [pHC, pHP]; // maybe you should check this, shouldn't it be let x = ['pHC','pHP']; ?

  component.aj(x, pI); // maybe you should check this, shouldn't it be component.aj(x, 'pI'); ?

  // check pI is in the array now since that's what the method does, push the element if it is not in the array
  expect(x).toContain(pl); // I used pI, but maybe check for 'pI' as my previous recommendations.
});
```

Comment: thaanks it works. But here:    expect(x.indexOf(pI)).not.toBe(-1)                               you dont use really the spy or the component. It seems like you just test PI in an array x thats all. when you delete the sypAJ  that will not change anything.